# Adobe Flash and TWAIN / DirectShow

Tags: flash, camera, video-streaming, driver

Usually Adobe Flash applications can access any usb-webcam.
I have a USB camera for microscopes which understands TWAIN and DirectShow.

Is there a possibility to access the video data from this camera with flash?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you are saying that you are unable to use your camera and aren't sure why, or if you are asking whether or not it's possible to access the raw video data from the camera.

If unable to access camera from Flash, then perhaps you'll need something that create an alternate DirectShow source that Flash can handle. You can do this yourself if familiar with C++ & DirectShow (it's not easy), otherwise maybe a product like this would help: http://www.e2esoft.cn/vcam/index.asp

If needing to access the raw data, you should be able to get it via the BitmapData API. Example: http://www.kasperkamperman.com/blog/flash-code/as3-apply-bitmap-filters-to-a-webcam-image/